# abort object3d.traverse in three.js

Tags: three.js

How can I abort the traverse when I traverse a three.js object?

```
scene.traverse(x => {
        if (x.userData) 
             // stop traversing here
});
```

return and break do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object3D.traverse code (r134)`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/00a692864f541a3ec194d266e220efd597eb28fa/src/core/Object3D.js#L503)

You would need to modify the `traverse` function to bail based on output from your callback function.

Something like this (untested):

```js
// three.js/src/core/Object3D.js

    traverse( callback ) {

        let bailedOut = callback( this );

        if( !bailedOut ) {

            const children = this.children;

            for ( let i = 0, l = children.length; i < l && !bailedOut; i ++ ) {

                bailedOut = children[ i ].traverse( callback );

            }

        }

        return bailedOut;

    }
```

And then call it like:

```js
function doTheThing( node ) {
    let bailOut = false;
    if( node.userData ) {
        bailOut = true;
    }
    else {
        // do the thing
    }
    return bailOut;
}

scene.traverse( doTheThing );
```

The processing basically continues until your callback returns `true`, at which point it triggers a cascade back up the `traverse` recursion chain until it exits the original call.

Comment: great answer, but need to edit the base three js code. So I think a simple solution is not there

Comment: @daniel I generally don't recommend it, but you _could_ "monkey-patch" the `Object3D.prototype.traverse` function.

Comment: @daniel But if you're using modules, you would need to patch the alternate implementation onto each object YOU create, since making it work via inheritance would be... ugly. (`import {Scene, Group, Mesh} from 'three'; Scene.prototype.traverse = altImpl; Group.prototype.traverse = altImpl; Mesh.prototype.traverse = altImpl;` lights, camera, etc.)